# Type Error #1009 in flash cs6 using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, typeerror, flash-cs6

I am actually trying to check whether a game's score is a high score. And then if it is, the score will be added to the leaderboard.
However I got this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at FlashGame_fla::MainTimeline/checkBananaHS()
```

In my game, in that particular frame, this is the code that would link to the checkBananaHS():

```
function rpslsWon():void 
{
    gameOverBananaMC.visible = true;
    bananaWinLose.visible = true;
    bananaWinLose.text = "Kampai " + cPlayerData.pName + "! You are totally bananas!! \nYour Score: " + pBananaScore;
    toMenuBtn.visible = true;
    rollAgainBtn.visible = true;
    toMenuBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click_backtoMain);
    rollAgainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backtoBanana);
    saveItBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkBananaHS);
    cPlayerData.pBananaScore = pBananaScore;
    saveData();
    tracePlayerData();
}
```

And this is the piece of code in the high score's frame:

```
var rpslsHighScore:int;
var rpslsHSName:String;
rpslsHighScore = 0;
rpslsHSName = "";

//rpslsHighScore = 0;
bananaWinnerDisplay.text = " ";
bananaScoreDisplay.text = "0";

function checkBananaHS(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if ((cPlayerData.pBananaScore > rpslsHighScore || 
    rpslsHighScore == 0) && cPlayerData.pBananaScore > 0)
    {
        trace("There's a new high score for Banana");
        rpslsHighScore = cPlayerData.pBananaScore;
        rpslsHSName = cPlayerData.pName;
        bananaScoreDisplay.text = "" + rpslsHighScore;
        bananaWinnerDisplay.text = rpslsHSName;
        saveData();
    }

}
```

I just can't manage to fix the error. Can anyone help me out? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables within `checkBananaHS()` are not set when it is called. So when you try to access a property of that object, it errors out because nothing exists.

Wit that in mind, that means one of the following objects are not yet set in your function:

- `cPlayerData`
- `bananaScoreDisplay`
- `bananaWinnerDisplay`

Run a trace on each of those, one at a time at the beginning of your function, and see which one doesn't return `[Object object]`

Comment: Yea, I ran the debugging tool in Flash, and it led me to this line bananaScoreDisplay.text = "" + rpslsHighScore; What does that mean?

Comment: That `banadaScroreDisplay` is not set yet (rather, `bananaScoreDisplay = null`). If it were not null, it would accept the value, even if `rpslsHighScore` were null/NaN

Comment: Means the object, bananaScoreDisplay has not been created?

Comment: Yes. There is no object assigned to the variable.

Comment: Hmm.. but I did. bananaScoreDisplay is actually a textbox, dynamic text. It's the instance name for this dynamic textbox. I really don't know what's wrong :(

Comment: That's what the error is saying. If that is the line the error is happening, I don't believe it could be anything else. if it was `rpslsHighScore`, it would just set the textfield to say `NaN` or `null`